How does my light fixture work and how can I replace it?
We just bought a house and aren’t loving the light fixture. I know most light fixtures you can replace yourself Or a company to do it for a small fee. However, ours is definitely a DIY situation from the previous previous seller. The light fixture only has wiring coming down from one side of the top and on top of the light fixture there is a switch and a dimmer. The light fixture itself is not associated with a light switch in the house, but wouldn’t be opposed if it was attached to the one 3 feet over near our garage door. Let me know what your thoughts are, and if this is something that you think we could do ourselves or would have to hire out!

We need pics of the light fixture and wiring as well as telling us where on the planet you live.

electricity is not something to work on when you are uncertain about it.

Confirm the light fixture has its own switch(dimmer) on the fixture.  If so, then the wires in the ceiling will be always hot and neutral.  If you want to add a wall switch, then you will need to trace the ceiling wires and hopefully they go down a wall.
